# fopen returns empty in php

Tags: csv, magento-1.9, fopen, php-5.5

I am trying to read a CSV file that has values in cells that are seperated by commas.

This is my code :-

```
if (($handle  = fopen($file_name['files']['tmp_name'], 'r')) !== FALSE) {
       while ($row  = fgetcsv($handle)) {
              echo '<pre>';
              print_r($row);
       }
}
```

Sometimes it works perfectly. But sometimes when I edit the CSV and add some sample values(or copy paste some previous values from above) the fopen does not work. It does not return anything. It is just empty.

If I revert the csv file to it's previous state it still works or if i put a single value instead of multiple it still works but not for values in a cell separated with commas.

Also, if I use pipe operator instead of commas in the csv it still works perfectly(this was done just for testing). But I only want to use comma delimiter in the csv.

Also, I am getting the file from request. If I use a file from my local storage it works fine. But when I upload it and then try to read it, then it does not work.

If I var_dump fopen() I get FALSE.

I have seen some questions related to this but nothing works. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's the size of the field uploaded?

Comment: there can be 1 to 10 values separated by commas. and I have two columns separated containing fields separated by commas

Comment: also the fields are numbers with single or double digits in first column and single, double or triple letters in 2nd column. All of them separated by commas in their respective column.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type _file_, not field. Could the max file upload size in PHP be interfering with your uploaded files? Have you tried var_dumping the whole `$_FILES` array?

Comment: var_dumping whole $_FILES array looks fine but when I echo fopen it, it is just blank. The size of the file can be big. I am uploading a list of products, so there can be a lot of products like in range of 100,000 or 1,000,000 with 5 t0 7 columns.

Comment: Then the file isn't present or can't be opened for another reason. Remember that uploaded files are only kept for the duration of the original request, so if you're trying to open it from a different process, it'll be gone.

Answer (score 0):

function `fopen()` will return FALSE only on an error.

It seems that your file actually was just uploaded. You should first move it from the location in `$_FILES` to another OR fully load it in memory (not recommended). Since on most Linux OSs the uploaded files are stored in `/tmp` PHP cannot guarantee that the file will be there for long-running scripts.

**So move the file and then open it.**
You can also check to see if the file is actually a CSV. There are 2 things to see:

1. Check that the file is actually there with `file_exists()`
2. Check the MIME type 
   This does not guarantee that the format of the file is totally correct

   ```
   $csv_mimetypes = array(
       'text/csv',
       'text/plain',
       'application/csv',
       'text/comma-separated-values',
       'application/excel',
       'application/vnd.ms-excel',
       'application/vnd.msexcel',
       'text/anytext',
       'application/octet-stream',
       'application/txt',
   );
   if (in_array($_FILES['upload']['type'], $csv_mimetypes)) {
       //MIME Type is correct....
   }
   ```
3. Validate the format
   This will guarantee the format. I will not go into details as there are many ways to achieve this.

After you have all these in place there should be no problem operating the file descriptor returned by `fopen()`. Also note that `fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.`

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Will try this when I get the chance.